# CSS Animation problems on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I am trying to make a part of my webpage animate once the page is fully loaded. The animation works perfectly on Internet Explorer 11 however it doesn't run on Chrome (version 31.0.1650.63 m) up to date version. The only time the animation actually runs properly on Chrome is if I reload the page, navigate away from the tab (So basically click on another tab that is open), wait for the page to load, then once I click back on the tab with the animation, the page then refreshes itself and loads the animation properly but if I reload the page and do not navigate away from the tab and simply wait for the page to load, the animation doesn't run. This seems really odd I and have no clue what to look for in the code because I assume it should work properly. Any clues??

Here's the css.

```
.mainpart
{
height:80%;
width:100%;
background-color:#eee;
white-space:nowrap;
z-index:10;
max-height:520px;

-webkit-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Safari 4+ */
-moz-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Fx 5+ */
-o-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Opera 12+ */
animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* IE 10+ */
}
@keyframes rotateInRight {
from {
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

to {
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
 }
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotateInRight {

from {
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

to {
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
 }

 @-moz-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
from {
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

to {
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
  }


 @-o-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
from {
-o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
-o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

to {
-o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

And here is the html with the mainpart class:

```
  div class="mainpart" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none; background-color: transparent;" tabindex="5000" > 
 ...........
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 10.

I cleaned up the CSS and removed the inline styles. Also, you were missing a `<` in the HTML.

- http://jsfiddle.net/R4THN/

HTML:

```
<div class="mainpart" tabindex="5000">
    ...........
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainpart {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
    max-height: 520px;

    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;

    -webkit-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Safari 4+ */
       -moz-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Fx 5+ */
         -o-animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* Opera 12+ */
            animation: rotateInRight 4s; /* IE 10+ */
}

@keyframes rotateInRight {
    from {
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateInRight {
    from {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
    from {
        -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateInUpLeft {
    from {
        -o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
}
```

So, if you still having issues, it must be with something else on your page, not this code specifically.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah it still doesn't work for some reason but, I took me entire code and copied and past the whole thing into the jsfiddle to see what would happen and yet, there is an animation that runs! So I don't know why or how IE and jsfiddle runs the animation with no problem yet Chrome can't for me. I'll try taking a different debugging approach to the whole problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Morelka I'd suggest copying the code here into some new files and make sure it works in all browers, then slowly add in the rest of your code (in pieces at a time) to see when it breaks.

Comment: Oh wow this was a stupid problem I had. :P I have a loading animation prior so rather than having my main page load bits and pieces at a time, I have a loading animation so all my images and other content loads onto the browser. Once everything is loaded completely, the loading animation is hidden and the content is then visible to the users. The problem that this was causing for me was I set the animation (the one I posted that I have a problem with, not the loading animation) doesn't run on Chrome but it does actually run.

Comment: So it runs while the loading animation runs so I just set an extra 10 seconds to the animation and shows on Chrome now. Basically  all is good now. I'll set your answer as correct since you've cleared a lot of the steps for me and you were very helpful. Thanks again.